# How to import a node module in an angular service.ts file

Tags: node.js, angular, redis

I am trying to implement redis functionality into my angular app's data.service.ts file so that I can use it for a signup and login page but every time I try to

```
import { redisImport } from '../../node_modules/redis';
import { cryptoImport } from '../../node_modules/crypto-browserify';
```

from my data.service.ts file it gives me errors such as

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/redis-parser/lib/hiredis.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'hiredis' in '/Users/myname/Desktop/Website/node_modules/redis-parser/lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/redis/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in '/Users/myname/Desktop/Website/node_modules/redis'
ERROR in ./node_modules/browserify-sign/browser/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '/Users/myname/Desktop/Website/node_modules/browserify-sign/browser'
ERROR in ./node_modules/cipher-base/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '/Users/myname/Desktop/Website/node_modules/cipher-base'
ERROR in ./node_modules/hash-base/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '/Users/myname/Desktop/Website/node_modules/hash-base'
ERROR in ./node_modules/redis/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tls' in '/Users/myname/Desktop/Website/node_modules/redis'
```

Comment: Why would you want to use Redis in the browser environment?

Comment: My it's so I can make calls directly to the database without having to go thorough and external api. I don't know if that is best practice or not, my original idea was to use express and have the website make calls to it but someone told me that express has some major vulnerabilities.

Comment: That's not a best practice. And you can't import Redis module in a browser environment, as it is supposed to be used in a server environment.